# Maven build - dependencies jars are corrupted

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a java jersey spring based maven application. I imported into my Eclipse, and when Maven starts downloading all dependencies (jars), they are all corrupted with very low sized files(<10kb). I deleted the `.m2` repo and ran the `mvn clean install` command multiple times, but I still get the same corrupted files.

Is there something wrong with `pom.xml`? Below is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <groupId>com.kreator.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>kreatorRestServices</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>kreatorRestServices Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>

        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.nettt</id>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!-- Specifying the Versions of Spring, Hiberante, MySQL etc -->
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>kreatorRestServices</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>kreatorbackendservices</appName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.3</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <artifactItems>
                                  <artifactItem>
                                      <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                      <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                      <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                  </artifactItem>
                              </artifactItems>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

And the error I see (when i run the build):

```
[WARNING] The POM for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

.
.
.
.

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 38 source files to C:\Users\charrj\Documents\kreatorjavatoolservices\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /C:/Users/charrj/Documents/kreatorjavatoolservices/src/main/java/com/pojo/Screen.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/charrj/Documents/kreatorjavatoolservices/src/main/java/com/pojo/Screen.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 2 warnings
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.1\postgresql-42.2.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.5.0\jackson-core-2.5.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.5.0\jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.5.0\jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-server\2.11\jersey-server-2.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\ext\jersey-spring3\2.11\jersey-spring3-2.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-json-jackson\2.22.2\jersey-media-json-jackson-2.22.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.11\aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.6.11\aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc5\11.2.0.2.0\ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.3.8.Final\hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-c3p0\4.3.8.Final\hibernate-c3p0-4.3.8.Final.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.1\postgresql-42.2.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.5.0\jackson-core-2.5.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.5.0\jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.5.0\jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-server\2.11\jersey-server-2.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\ext\jersey-spring3\2.11\jersey-spring3-2.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-json-jackson\2.22.2\jersey-media-json-jackson-2.22.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.11\aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.6.11\aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.2.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc5\11.2.0.2.0\ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.3.8.Final\hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-c3p0\4.3.8.Final\hibernate-c3p0-4.3.8.Final.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\charrj\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar; error in opening zip file
```

Any help will be much appreciated. I can't go and download jars manually, because I'm trying to deploy the app on Heroku as well, so that anyway will try to download the files again. So it is **not** just my local `.m2` repo alone that's affected because of this.

Comment: Try re- installing the parent POM by `mvn install -N`

Comment: Does not help here. I strongly recommend to use repositories only via https and never via http and second turn on checksum checking see https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Ah what I missed in your configuration is that you are using: `https://mvnrepository.com/` this can not be used as a repository cause it's a search engine not a Maven repository in contradiction to the name!!!

Comment: In addition to others' comments: you will need to *delete* the currently installed jars after correcting your pom file (delete the entire artifact version's directory for maven to search afresh).

Comment: Apart from that I don't understand why you have configured so much repositories? Do you use things which are not available from central repository? If not no supplemental configuration is needed.

Comment: Use correct maven repository URL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you!! that worked.

Comment: @ladyDon303 That should mean you don't have any repository configuration in your pom.xml ..correct?

Comment: Yes thats Correct. @khmarbaise